# Android - Google Map API v2 - Unfortunately, application has stopped

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps

Some days I'm having trouble with Google Maps 
I will do everything I will not be able to run the program 
I'm grateful for your guidance

Android - Google Map API v2 - Unfortunately, application has stopped. Force closing every time

my xml :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"       
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" 

    >

    <fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

manifest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.m.r.rahimi.zade.map"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <permission
        android:name="com.m.r.rahimi.zade.map.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.m.r.rahimi.zade.map.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

     <library android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
   <!-- The following two permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended. -->
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <!-- Required OpenGL ES 2.0. for Maps V2 -->
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />





    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" 
        android:debuggable="false">

        <activity
            android:name="com.m.r.rahimi.zade.map.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
         <!-- Goolge API Key -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyBubw0ar9XMkxQzAxLxBu7LxG6GbfJpixA" />




    </application>

</manifest>
```

activity :

```
package com.m.r.rahimi.zade.map;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {


    private GoogleMap googleMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         try {
                // Loading map
                initilizeMap();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    private void initilizeMap() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         if (googleMap == null) {
                googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                        R.id.map)).getMap();

                // check if map is created successfully or not
                if (googleMap == null) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }
            }
        }


     @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            initilizeMap();
        }

    }
```

logcat :

```
02-10 15:13:44.230: D/AndroidRuntime(1049): Shutting down VM
02-10 15:13:44.230: W/dalvikvm(1049): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb4b05b90)
02-10 15:13:44.290: E/AndroidRuntime(1049): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-10 15:13:44.290: E/AndroidRuntime(1049): Process: com.m.r.rahimi.zade.map, PID: 1049
02-10 15:13:44.290: E/AndroidRuntime(1049): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.m.r.rahimi.zade.map/com.m.r.rahimi.zade.map.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class fragment
02-10 15:13:44.290: E/AndroidRuntime(1049):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2176)
02-10 15:13:44.290: E/AndroidRuntime(1049):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
02-10 15:13:44.290: E/AndroidRuntime(1049):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:135)
02-10 15:13:44.290: E/AndroidRuntime(1049):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
02-10 15:13:44.290: E/AndroidRuntime(1049):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
02-10 15:13:44.290: E/AndroidRuntime(1049):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-10 15:13:44.290: E/AndroidRuntime(1049):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
02-10 15:13:44.290: E/AndroidRuntime(1049):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-10 15:13:44.290: E/AndroidRuntime(1049):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-10 15:13:44.290: E/AndroidRuntime(1049):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
02-10 15:13:44.290: E/AndroidRuntime(1049):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
02-10 15:13:44.290: E/AndroidRuntime(1049):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-10 15:13:44.290: E/AndroidRuntime(1049): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class fragment
02-10 15:13:44.290: E/AndroidRuntime(1049):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
02-10 15:13:44.290: E/AndroidRuntime(1049):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
02-10 15:13:44.290: E/AndroidRuntime(1049):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
02-10 15:13:44.290: E/AndroidRuntime(1049):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
02-10 15:13:44.290: E/AndroidRuntime(1049):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
02-10 15:13:44.290: E/AndroidRuntime(1049):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
02-10 15:13:44.290: E/AndroidRuntime(1049):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1928)
02-10 15:13:44.290: E/AndroidRuntime(1049):     at com.m.r.rahimi.zade.map.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:21)
02-10 15:13:44.290: E/AndroidRuntime(1049):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5243)
02-10 15:13:44.290: E/AndroidRuntime(1049):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
02-10 15:13:44.290: E/AndroidRuntime(1049):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2140)
02-10 15:13:44.290: E/AndroidRuntime(1049):     ... 11 more
02-10 15:13:44.290: E/AndroidRuntime(1049): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 4132500 but found 0.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
02-10 15:13:44.290: E/AndroidRuntime(1049):     at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.n(Unknown Source)
02-10 15:13:44.290: E/AndroidRuntime(1049):     at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Unknown Source)
02-10 15:13:44.290: E/AndroidRuntime(1049):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.q.v(Unknown Source)
02-10 15:13:44.290: E/AndroidRuntime(1049):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.q.u(Unknown Source)
02-10 15:13:44.290: E/AndroidRuntime(1049):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer.initialize(Unknown Source)
02-10 15:13:44.290: E/AndroidRuntime(1049):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$b.eb(Unknown Source)
02-10 15:13:44.290: E/AndroidRuntime(1049):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$b.a(Unknown Source)
02-10 15:13:44.290: E/AndroidRuntime(1049):     at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.a(Unknown Source)
02-10 15:13:44.290: E/AndroidRuntime(1049):     at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.onInflate(Unknown Source)
02-10 15:13:44.290: E/AndroidRuntime(1049):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
02-10 15:13:44.290: E/AndroidRuntime(1049):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:290)
02-10 15:13:44.290: E/AndroidRuntime(1049):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
02-10 15:13:44.290: E/AndroidRuntime(1049):     ... 21 more
02-10 15:13:49.820: I/Process(1049): Sending signal. PID: 1049 SIG: 9
```

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 4132500 but found 0.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />`

Answer (score 2):

As 323go notes, you are missing:

```
<meta-data
  android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
  android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
```

This is a relatively new requirement, and so older blog posts and such will not mention it. Just add it next to your existing `<meta-data>` element.